# Undefined AITOC function at app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitoptionstemplate/Model/Observer.php on line 11

Tags: magento

I copied the website files of a live magento website to my local machine. I try to open the home page and a blank white screen turns up.
In the apache2 error log, I find the following line:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function kYESppcDEoBrEZyw() in .../httpdocs/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitoptionstemplate/Model/Observer.php on line 11

The culprit line is:

```
if(Aitoc_Aitsys_Abstract_Service::initSource(__FILE__,'Aitoc_Aitoptionstemplate'))
{ kYESppcDEoBrEZyw('e71e3cbbed8235b2be55dfb8db045b91');
```

and the other bracket closes at the end of the file.

It seems there is an extension called Aitoc custom options template installed. That's fine but what is the purpose of the strangely named function? And how is it working on the live site?

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes cleared the cache. I contacted support. It might be a license issue. I'll post an update.

Comment: Yes, I have to install the license for the extension locally for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to be careful here since the website uses 3rd party extensions and the extension protects its license - it doesn't allow using the extension without installing the license first and throws the above error.
So you'll need to install the license on the local/dev server first before starting work on the website. You can also disable the extension(for AITOC) and get the website working by following the instructions at:
http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_custom_options_templates.html#docs

I did disable it and I am able to run the website on the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.One more extension was installed in my site "Custom Product Preview".
So some files were missing while installing the extension.

When we uploaded the same missing files.Then refreshed the admin section.It asked for the license information after providing license information everything worked fine.
So be careful while installing the extension.
Also install the license carefully.

For me "/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/etc/compilation.xml" was also missing.